# Case statement for validating year

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking to write a `case` statement that will verify if a 4 digit year is correct or not.

For example, if I select the `ID` and `DT` (datatype is DATE), and the date is wrong, don't show it.

```
SELECT ID, to_char(DT,'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss') from DB_TABLE
```

Would result in the following:

```
ID  DT
1   0208-03-25 12:26:00
2   2008-04-01 13:45:18
3   2000-11-15 13:45:18
```

My goal is to write a query that puts null in the date column when the date is not correct:

```
select ID, case when DT is not valid then null else dt from DB_TABLE
```

Would result in the following:

```
ID  DT
1   null
2   2008-04-01 13:45:18
3   2000-11-15 13:45:18
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does you `dt` field not have a `date` datatype?

Comment: @bluefeet Yes, the datatype for the DT column is date.

Comment: `0208` is a valid year. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/208 has some interesting facts about it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
select ID,
  case
    when extract(year from DT) between 1900 and 2050
      then DT
    else null
  end as DT
from DB_TABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
    select case 
       when length (to_char(extract(year from to_date('0208-03-25','YYYY-MM-DD')))) < 4 
          or extract(year from to_date('0208-03-25','YYYY-MM-DD')) not between 1800 and 2013
           then NULL           
       else to_date('0208-03-25','YYYY-MM-DD')
       end as DT
  from dual;
```

You can define your own comparison logics as apposed to above ones above.

So for your query-

```
select ID, case 
           when length (to_char(extract(year from DT))) < 4 
              or extract(year from DT) not between 1800 and 2013
               then NULL
           else DT
           end as DATE_DT
 from DB_TABLE;
```

The reason I had `< 4` for the year is `0208` is considered as a valid year in Oracle, however this could be checked by the range check using `between`, so you should be ok with only `between` for year if you have a year range like `1900` to `2015`. If you don't have a year range then the `length` check should suffice to find "pre-historic" years in the data.